# Android: how to disable controls during progress bar is active

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-progressbar

I show my infinte progress bar in the action bar "as usual":

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
...
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
...
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

and the real work is done in a background thread (AsyncTask)

The problem: all controls on the UI are enabled, so the user can continue to modify the underlying data before the long lasting process is finished.

Simply disabling all controls is not possible because when disabling an EditText, also the keyboard is closed automatically by Android.

Any ideas how to prevent user input during the background work?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 9):

What you can do is to bring up an invisible dialog and prevent it from being cancellable. It will show whatever is underneath it but disable all underlying user interaction. Then once you are done with your business you simply dismiss it and go on with your life:

```
Dialog mOverlayDialog = new Dialog(mContext, android.R.style.Theme_Panel); //display an invisible overlay dialog to prevent user interaction and pressing back
mOverlayDialog.setCancelable(false);
mOverlayDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 5):

try putting `progressDialog.setcancelable(false);`

Comment: I have no ProgressBar (please see above)

Comment: how will you show to user that you are doing somethng in background and you dont want any user to touch anythng.....


the best way is to use the progressdialog which shows loading on the screen....

Comment: my code snippet above already shows an infinite progress circle in the right corner of the action bar

Comment: set the clickable of the parent View =  false  ... i think this can help you...  I did not understand why are you avoiding the progressDialog ??

Comment: clickable == false does not prevent e.g. editing some text in an EditText

Comment: @avoiding the progressDialog:

Comment: @avoiding the progressDialog:very often my tasks are often very, very short, so popping up a dialog is annoying

Comment: very often my tasks are often very, very short, so popping up a dialog is annoying

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to set just the Property of Activity. Instead Bring up a dialog using 
ProgressDialog, so that Ui will not be accessible

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Please wait...", true);
```

Edit:
If you do not want to use ProgressDialog, get the Root Layout and call

```
layout.setEnabled(false)
```

Comment: I know the ProgressBar but do not want to use it in this case.

Comment: So you want the whole layout to be dimmed?

Comment: dimmed or at least "readonly" (= no control may be modified, no button pressed,....)

Comment: layout.setEnabled(false) does not prevent e.g. editing some text in an EditText.

Comment: You are absolutely right about using a progress DIALOG instead of a progress bar.  The dialog will hold the focus of the screen, preventing any user activity from reaching the Activity below.

But layout.setEnabled(false) does not propagate through to its children, making that solution not feasible.

Answer (score 1):

in case, if somebody else faced the same problem,

to disable editing the text use: `EditText.setFocusable(false);`

to enable editing: `EditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);`