# Disabling all touches when loading indicator is shown

Tags: android

I have a simple main layout, and then I add a fragment layout that only shows an indicator loading on top of that main layout.  Problem is that I can still press the buttons behind the loading indicator.

Is there anyway to disable touches so it doesn't pass through to the back?  I don't want to have to disable each button on the main screen one by one.

Comment: I always just manually set my buttons to isClickable(false) when any custom popup is active. But I'm interested to know if there's a cleaner solution.

Comment: You probably need to disable the underlying layout while the indicator is active: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12300796/android-how-to-disable-controls-during-progress-bar-is-active

Comment: I believe I've tried that but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you considered using a `ProgressDialog` instead? That should block the activity behind.

Comment: I checked it out, but it seems it's more than I need.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could set the "clickable" attribute to "true" in the layout that contains your ProgressBar:

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/progressBarContainer"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Then while the ProgressBar is visible, its container (which fills the entire screen although it's invisible) will intercept any click events so they won't fall through to the underlying layout while your ProgressBar is showing.

To use this, do this when you want to show the ProgressBar:

```
findViewById(R.id.progressBarContainer).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and then do this when you're done with it:

```
findViewById(R.id.progressBarContainer).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

For instance, if you're using this in an AsyncTask, you could make it visible in onPreExecute(), then make it invisible in onPostExecute().

Comment: Glad I could help.  That's what I'm using now too.

Answer (score 1):

Return `true` while you wanna block user touches. Override this method in your `Activity`.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent( MotionEvent event ) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a much better solution than manually disabling 10+ buttons :)

Comment: The other method is cleaner for me where you set clickable="true" because now any activity that uses this fragment will have the background's view disabled.